# OpenGL - attempt to use VBO causes an error

Tags: opengl, access-violation, vbo

I am having a problem when trying to use VBO in OpenGL (using loads of tutorials on this) -
each time I call glBufferData an "access violation in atioglxx.dll" error pops up. I've been trying to use different data types of data, vertexes and so on, but no success.
 The pseudo-code is the following:

```
GLDouble[] VertexArray = {1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0};  
glGenBuffers(1, @VertexList);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VertexList);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(VertexArray), @VertexArray, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Comment: Have you check that your graphic card supports VBO ? Do you have the latest drivers ?

Comment: I am quiet sure any modern card has VBO support. As for mine, it is ATI 6990.

Comment: Which language is that you're using?

Comment: If this is Pascal and vertexarray is dynamic array then you should try @VertexArray[0] instead.

Comment: It is a pascal indeed, but it has nothing to do with language - I've tried the same in C++.

Comment: Verify the glGenBuffers and glBindBuffer work correctly first.  I mean you can check with glGetError to see.  I've got a feeling it might not have bound correctly.

Comment: what do you use for Extension Loading? Is there any GLEW/GLEE? it seems that we have some problems with memory or problems with function pointer for opengl code

Comment: Hopefully you made an OpenGL context first?

Comment: Just to make sure: Did you apply the fix Ville suggested? Do you use &VertexArray[0] (or just VertexArray - I'm not sure if C++ makes a difference) in your C++ code? The error sounds very much like you don't.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(VertexArray), VertexArray, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```